# Notice: Undefined index: title in ....... on line 27

Tags: php, html, mysql

actualmente poseo un nuevo error que la verdad no entiendo como solucionarlo:

ARCHIVO: posts.php

```
<?php 

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/database/db.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/helpers/validatePost.php');

$table = 'posts';

$errors = array();
$id = '';
$title = '';

$posts = selectAll($table);


if (isset($_POST['add-post'])) {
    $errors = validatePost($_POST);
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        unset($_POST['add-post']);
        $posts = create($table, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Capitulo creado correctamente';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/posts/index.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $posts = selectOne($table, ['id' => $id]);
    $id = $posts['id'];
    $title = $posts['title'];
}

if (isset($_GET['del_id'])){
    $id = $_GET['del_id'];    
    $count = delete($table, $id);
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Capitulo eliminado correctamente';
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
    header('location: ../../admin/posts/index.php');
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['update-post'])){
    $errors = validatePost($_POST); 
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        unset($_POST['update-post'], $_POST['id']);
        $posts = update($table, $id, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Capitulo actualizado correctamente';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/topics/index.php');
        exit();        
    } else {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
}
} 
?>
```

ARCHIVO: create.php

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/controllers/posts.php');?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

  <!-- Custom Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../style.css">

  <!-- Admin Styling -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../admin.css">

  <title>Admin - Create Posts</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- header -->
  <header class="clearfix">
    <div class="logo">
      <!-- <img src="images/logo-placeholder.png" alt="Logo"> -->
    </div>
    <div class="fa fa-reorder menu-toggle"></div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="userinfo">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            My Web Test
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="logout">logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- // header -->

  <div class="admin-wrapper clearfix">
    <!-- Left Sidebar -->
    <div class="left-sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="../posts/index.php">Manage Posts</a></li>
        <li><a href="../topics/index.php">Manage Topics</a></li>
        <li><a href="../users/index.php">Manage Users</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- // Left Sidebar -->

    <!-- Admin Content -->
    <div class="admin-content clearfix">
      <div class="button-group">
        <a href="create.php" class="btn btn-sm">Add Posts</a>
        <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-sm">Manage Posts</a>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <h2 style="text-align: center;">AÑADIR NUEVO CAPITULO</h2>
          <?php include('../../app/helpers/formErrors.php');?>

        <form action="create.php" method="post">
          <div class="input-group">
            <label>Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" class="text-input">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <button type="submit" name="add-post" class="btn" >Crear</button>
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- // Admin Content -->

  </div>


  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- CKEditor 5 -->
  <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/11.2.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

  <!-- Custome Scripts -->
  <script src="../../scripts.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

ARCHIVO: validatePost.php

```
<?php
    
    function validatePost($post){
      
    $errors = array();
    
    if (empty($post['title'])){
        array_push($errors, 'Necesitas ingresar un nombre para la categoria.');
    }

        
        $existingPost = selectOne('posts', ['title' => $post['title']]);
        if ($existingPost) {
            array_push($errors, 'Ya existe este capitulo.');
        }
        
        return $errors;
    }


?>
```

Lo que intento hacer es crear POSTS (publicaciones) al ingresar a mi web e ir a create.php y darle click al boton 'Crear' me aparece los errores:

Notice: Undefined index: title in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\helpers\validatePost.php on line 12
Notice: Undefined index: title in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\controllers\posts.php on line 26

¿Alguien me puede ayudar a solucionarlo?

PD: La mysql esta bien creada y con los nombres bien establecidos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta indicando que no viene un valor pata "title" en la data recibida por POST (`$_POST['title']` no esta definida). Pueden ser 2 motivos principales:

***No se esta cargando la pagina usando POST*** (la peticion no es una respuesta por enviar datos de un formulario POST), puede ser cuando cargas la pagina `create.php` por primera vez directamente por la URL. En este caso puedes agregar una condicion en `posts.php` para no realizar nada hasta que se envien datos:

```
if (!$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST") {
    // no realizar operaciones, no se han enviado datos aun
    return;
}
```

***No se esta enviando la variable `title` en los datos de POST***. Dentro de los datos del `form` HTML no existe un campo con nombre title (`input name="title"`), puede que hayas asignado mal el nombre del control (`name="title"` en vez de `name="name"`):

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" class="text-input">
```

Comment: Gracias!!! me funciono correctamente la segunda solución y fue cambiar: name="title" no entiendo como se me escapo eso pero muchas gracias.